# How to prove program solves the problem?

Tags: correctness-proof, hoare-logic, program-correctness

I am preparing for the exam on Theory of Programming class. Now I am trying to solve the task from the sample paper:

**Task description starts here**

Given the following problem:
A problem is given by its specification:

[image]

Let S denote the following program:

[image]

[image]

Write down the conditions that are sufficient to prove that the given S program solves the given problem.
Prove that S is a solution of the given problem. Detailed explanation is required.

**Task description ends here**

I tried to solve this task as sequence according to this:

[image]

[image]

My question: Am I on the right path? If yes, what should I take instead of S2? If I am on the wrong path - what should I do to solve this task?

It would be great if you could suggest the book, webpage, video tutorial which contains similar tasks.